# google play service error - meta data

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services, android-virtual-device

Sorry if this is a duplicate question ... but of the many answers I found, I still have not found an answer that I can use or my application

**this is my android manifest :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="co.id.adhe.agmv2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<permission
    android:name="co.id.adhe.agmv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="co.id.adhe.agmv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICE"/>
<!-- the following two permission are not required to use google maps android API V2,
but are recommended -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="4452000" />

    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCbQI8EPBa1wy3lypoq1DW9tkMzQXi8JnE"/>        

    <activity
        android:name="co.id.adhe.agmv2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

**this my fragment main :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="co.id.adhe.agmv2.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

**my avd setting :**
target    : Google APIs
platform  : 4.2.2
API Level : 17

this is my logcat eror :

```
05-23 15:45:57.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1134): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }

05-23 15:45:57.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)

05-23 15:45:57.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)

05-23 15:45:57.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)

05-23 15:45:57.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)

05-23 15:45:57.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)

05-23 15:45:57.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)

05-23 15:45:57.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$5.onClick(Unknown Source)

05-23 15:45:57.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)

05-23 15:45:57.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)

05-23 15:45:57.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)

05-23 15:45:57.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

05-23 15:45:57.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

05-23 15:45:57.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

05-23 15:45:57.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

05-23 15:45:57.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

05-23 15:45:57.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

05-23 15:45:57.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

05-23 15:45:57.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

05-23 15:46:00.183: I/Process(1134): Sending signal. PID: 1134 SIG: 9
```

I followed some of the answers in forums like google update service play in the sdk and add meta tags... but avd is still asking for update google avd play service..

When I am clicking update direct application crashes...

Any advice?

Comment: you require google play services. try testing on a device

Comment: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }

com.android.vending package is missing that means play store is not installed.

Comment: for run your project you need device or 3rd party android emulator like genymotion.

Comment: I've been installing the genymotion but still encountered the same problem,
still asked to install google play service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is error in your project is related to google play services,
either run your project in device or try 3rd party emulator a [genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/).

Comment: I've been installing the genymotion but still encountered the same problem,
still asked to install google play service

Comment: yes thats right ... because in the new genymotion they not prove the google service so you have to install it manually
download it and drag and drop it in genymotin emulator http://goo.im/gapps/gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip 

and you need to other zip file for ARM you have to doenload ARM V1.1  zip file and same you have to drag drop it in genymotion

after do it your setup will be done

Comment: thank you to the explanation.. but I found a more complete web..,
we can choose google apps with the proper purposes and their application is in the zip, this website where I downloaded the google app http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/Google_Apps#Universal_Packages_2

once downloaded, drag and drop the zip file into the genymotion emulator..,
then there will be some errors, but let it go,

after completion of the update google play service through google play store, my google map v2 app now is able to run well in the emulator...,

once again thank you for the explanation @Govind Rathod

Comment: ok Good after all whatever way it was done. main thing is that, yes and your suggested link is redirect the same at `gapps`. 
welcome every time.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your mainifest file inside application tag

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your google api key" />
```